# retrieve data from sql of particular date & show message

Tags: php, sql

I wan to retrieve date from sql of a particular date and want to show message if the data is not available of particular date.

Comment: I'm happy for you; there's something you want to do. So go out and do it!

Comment: What is stopping you from doing it?

Comment: lol,I need code of php for this :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE date = 'dateYouWantToCheck'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); //count number of rows returned

if($num_rows > 0)
{
   //Show details here
}
else
{
   echo "No match found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo Code

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(X.DATA) > 0 THEN X.DATA ELSE 'No Data Found' END

FROM 

(SELECT DATA FROM <TABLE NAME> WHERE DATE = <SOME DATE> )X
```